# Partial Sandbox data segementation?

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, documentation

Someone knows the logic behind the dataload of a Partial Sandbox?

In Salesforce documentation there is only something about the creation of the sandbox template, but not about how Salesforce chooses the data to load. On which criteria it's based. Most recently? Relations?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting question and it seems to be answered at a very high level here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AFDRIA4

*While copying data into a Partial Data Sandbox, automatic queries will be created for your template internally and upto 10,000 records per Object Type will be retrieved. The Sample, which is the result of these automatic queries, will be “Random”, but they will “mostly” bring data in the order it was created. Please also note, there is no current method to specify data to be included.*